# Tabela não quebra a linha

Tags: html, jquery, tabela-html

É o seguinte eu estou usando uma tabela do site: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) e o que se passa é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o texto fica todo em linha o que faz com que se torne difícil de ler porque tem de se fazer scroll a minha duvida é como faço para que ele faça parágrafos automáticos ou seja com que a tabela quebre a linha.

```
<div class="card-block">
   <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
        <table id="basic-btn" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Nome do Cliente</th>
                 <th>Serial Number</th> 
                 <th>Fabrincante</th>
                 <th>Modelo</th>
                 <th>Avaria</th>
                 <th>Causa</th>
                 <th>Relatório</th>
                 <th>Data</th>
                 <th>Num Obra</th>
                 <th style="min-width:80px;">Ação</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>Exemplo/td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td style="word-wrap:break-word"> </td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td>Exemplo</td>
                  <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i></button>
                     <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#awesome-modal" class="btn btn-danger md-effect-1 apagar"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></button>
                  </td>
               </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: a tabela já está responsiva, o que você precisa é quebrar a linha

Comment: exato obrigado! faltavame a palavra

Comment: sim isso funciona para a coluna mas para o texto nao

Comment: eu penso que seja algo do datatables mesmo

Comment: Só retirei o php que é o código que esta a ir buscar ao banco de dados

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar [`white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) para quebrar strings longas. O Datatables não possui um estilo específico para isso. Você pode adicionar um CSS na página para a tabela pegando pelo `id`:

```
#basic-btn tr td{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Ou via jQuery:

```
$("#basic-btn tr td").css("white-space","pre-wrap");
```

Comment: Perfeito o seu funcionou

Comment: @Shider Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado eu!! 3º vez em 2 dias Você é demais cara @dvd

Comment: @Shider Que nada, vc que eh. Tah aprendendo rápido :D

Comment: Quando o professor é bom o aluno aprende rápido!!

Answer (score 2):

Basta você definir a table para `table-layout:fixed` e todas as `td` para `word-wrap:break-word`

A exemplo do `DataTables` que mencionou, utilizei o seguinte código para a tabela:

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable dtr-inline" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed">
```

> Detalhe para: `table-layout:fixed`

criei um style css para a td:

```
<style>
  td{
       word-wrap:break-word;
    }
</style>
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Não sei porque no meu nao deu mesmo colocando aquilo que indicou

Comment: verifique a class da table, se está igual

Comment: eu mudei mas deixou de dar mas já tenho a solução obrigado na mesma!!

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso em especifico, a quebra não aconteceu pois entendeu-se que havia apenas uma palavra, sem espaços. Tente colocar alguns espaços, como se estivesse formando uma frase, ai acredito que o dataTable irá fazer a quebra automática da linha.